# Multiple Generic Types

Tags: java, generics, extends

So first of all, I will specify that my question is not referring to having multiple generics being applied to a class. I know you can do that simply with a comma.

My question is if there is a way to have multiple possible extensions for a generics. For example:

```
public class Foo<? extends String>{}
public class Bar<? extends StringBuilder>{}
//combined
public class FooBar<? extends String, StringBuilder>{}
//or perhaps
public class FooBar<? extends String || StringBuilder>{}
```

I know the FooBar class will not compile but I hope that is helpful in explaining my question and the specified intent. To lastly reiterate my question: is it possible for two classes to be extended in the generic clause or a way that would simulate such an action indirectly?

Note I am **not** asking how generics work, **nor** how extensions work, **nor** anything involving how and when to use of generics, for I already know this. If the question needs clarification, I will edit to provide further understanding to the best of my abilities.

Comment: Can you provide a full example? because this question isn't really clear

Comment: @Emax I am not quite sure what else to define. The class is there, the generics are there. And the intent is such that "?" can extend both String and StringBuilder. If it were such that ? extends Number, then the generic could be Number, Integer, Double, etc. But the intent is two siblings, instead of a parent-child relationship.

Comment: So if I understood correctly, you want to have generic which would be either from String **or** StringBuilder hierarchy?

Comment: @FilipRistic correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible for a class to extend both `String` and `StringBuilder` since classes only have one parent class. However, they can implement multiple interfaces, which you can specify with `&`.

```
class FooBar<T extends String & Runnable & Collection<Integer>> {}
```

(Note that `String` is final so it's not actually possible to satisfy the above constraint.)

Comment: Thank you so much. I presume the reason, is the same reason multiple inheritance for Classes is not allowed?

Answer (score 1):

So what you are asking isn't possible out of the box as John has said, but you can still achieve similar behavior using so called `Either` type which is used to represent situation where you can either 1 of 2 types.

You can easily find fully implemented `Either` class with simple google search, for example this one on [github](https://github.com/spencerwi/Either.java)

For code snippet bellow lets consider this simplified version:

```
public class Either<L, R> {
    private final L left;
    private final R right;
    private final boolean isRight;

    private Either(L left, R right, boolean isRight) {
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
        this.isRight = isRight;
    }

    public static <L, R> Either<L, R> left(L left){
        return new Either<>(left, null, false);
    }

    public static <L, R> Either<L, R> right(R right){
        return new Either<>(null, right, true);
    }

    public <T>  T fold(Function<L,T> foldLeft, Function<R, T> foldRight){
        return isRight ? foldRight.apply(right) : foldLeft.apply(left);
    }
}
```

Now lets say you have interface with some method that should accept `String` or `StringBuilder`:

```
public interface IFooBar <T extends Either<? extends String, ? extends StringBuilder>>{
    String  doSomething(T t);
}
```

And implementation:

```
class FooBar implements IFooBar<Either<String, StringBuilder>> {
    @Override
    public String doSomething(Either<String, StringBuilder> either) {
        return either.fold(s -> "String: " + s, sb -> "StringBuilder:" + sb);
    }
}
```

Then you can simply use it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    IFooBar<Either<String, StringBuilder>> fooBar = new FooBar();
    // Since in this case it is single method interface you can even use lambda expression
    // IFooBar<Either<String, StringBuilder>> fooBar = either -> either.fold(s -> "String: " + s, sb -> "StringBuilder:" + sb);
    System.out.println(fooBar.doSomething(Either.left("Foo")));
    System.out.println(fooBar.doSomething(Either.right(new StringBuilder("Bar"))));
}
```

I hope that this helps you.

Comment: I'll try this. Based on a cursory look, seems like this could work. Thank you.